# ios-charts: Can Selecting A Node Trigger A Labels Text To Change?

Tags: swift, ios-charts

I am using [ios-charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) in swift language. I'm wanting to show more data about each node when they are selected. A marker wouldn't have enough space for all the info I am wanting to display so I am wanting to display it all in a dedicated label on the ViewController itself. Is there any way to do this?

I got the `chartValueSelected` method working but am not sure how to utilize it for this.

Comment: So you need to have single label showing the details of any selected node? Can you show the current code for `chartValueSelected`

Comment: Never mind, I got chartValueSelected. Edited post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Included `ChartViewDelegate`

&

```
 chtChart.delegate = self
```

I have an array called `textNotes` thats corresponds to each data entry in the array and made a label called `infoLabelChart`

```
    func chartValueSelected(_ chartView: ChartViewBase, entry: 
    ChartDataEntry, highlight: Highlight) {
        let pos = NSInteger(entry.x)
        infoLabelChart.text = "\(textNotes[pos])"
    }
```